# Excel Equation of line not correct

Tags: excel, math, graph, polynomial-math, trendline

I'm hoping someone will be able to tell me why the equation that Excel generated is not giving the correct results as it is graphed correctly.

I have some X and Y points that I will list below. I plotted those points in Excel and then plotted the trend line, and had it show me the equation of the trendline. When I take the equation and then plug in the X values I get very different answers back.

**X and Y Values**

```
X     Y
0     3
3     2
5    1.4
7    1
10   0.5
18   0.1
```

When I set the intercept to 3, the equation of the trendline is `y = 0.0088x5 - 0.1457x4 + 0.8753x3 - 2.224x2 + 1.4798x + 3`

**Screenshot of Excel window with equation**

[image: Excel screen shot]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tested with Mathematica and the formula gives me the same result: f(3)=1.3932. How did you draw the graph? Maybe the formula is a bit different?

Comment: I tried to fit the same data with a polynomial of degree 5 and I get totally different result. How did you obtain this equation? I get: 0.000039923*x^5 - 0.00152189*x^4 + 0.0192992*x^3 - 0.0840135*x^2 - 0.217128*x + 3

Comment: I drew the graph by just inserting a chart, and then just input the column array into the `add data` section. Then to make the trend line I just click on the line to select it and then right click and then go down to add trendline, and Excel does the rest. I tried your equation and its basically spot on.

Comment: I suggest you redo the trendline. I do not have Excel (sorry), but with both Mathematica and Google Sheets, I get the same polynomial. So the problem seems to be with your graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you didn't set up your graph correctly.

- Select a single cell in your table
- Insert/Scatter (and decide which you want with regard to markers, etc)
- Select the line and add Trendline
- Set you parameters for the trendline
- If you want to get the formula for the trendline from the "show formula" option, be sure to **format** the trendline label to be numeric with 15 decimals.  Otherwise the equation will certainly not work, even if it appears to be correct.

[image]

Note that you can obtain the formula directly using the `LINEST` worksheet function.

```
=LINEST(Y,X^{1,2,3,4,5}) returns the array:    

  {0.0000399230399230442,-0.00152188552188569,0.0192991822991846,-0.0840134680134806,-0.217128427128402,2.99999999999999}
```

*The last value in the array is the y-intercept*
*The slight differences are due to the use of different algorithms for the two methods.*

Comment: This is 100% my fault for graphing, I used a line graph and just set my X labels to my X values. Thank you for seeing my mistake on this.

Comment: @laxer Yes, with a line chart, the x-axis values that you are using are interpreted merely as labels.  The actual values associated with those "labels" will be `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` which is why you are seeing an incorrect equation.